# How to get Selenium to wait for a transition page to redirect before running an assertion

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a fairly standard situation:  Click a button, it loads a transition page with a progress bar or something, and then that page redirects to the next page, which takes a while to load.

I want to run assertions on the final page, not the transition page. How do I tell Selenium IDE to wait till the final page loads before performing the assertions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple approach would be wait for some "particular" text on that final page, see "waitForText" command for further info on it.

Comment: sweet. One thing I did was add a setTimeout target=XXXX (in ms) command before the waitForText, and that cut down the time it waited when the assertion wasn't met.

Thanks a lot, John.

Comment: You can also use waitForLocation and give it the url.

Comment: how do you do waitForLocation ?

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("my-url"))

Comment: driver.wait(until.urlContains("part_of_expected_URL"))
or 
driver.wait(until.urlIs("expected_URL"))

Answer (score 12):

To add to John's approach, you can use the Selenium **wait** mechanism to verify that elements on your final page are present like so:

**Java:**

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10); // seconds
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("foo")));
```

**Ruby:**

```rb
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 10) # seconds
wait.until { driver.find_element(id: "foo") }
```

This will properly follow any redirects involved.

Example from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Comment: It expects a unit instead of an int now, so you have to use `Duration.of(10, SECONDS)` instead of just 10.

Answer (score 4):

You could call wait_for_page twice in a row. The first waits for the redirect, the second for the final page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wait until the page title is an expected value:

```php
$driver->wait()->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleIs('New page title from redirect'));
```