# expected_conditions with Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium

I want to load my driver until my current_url contains "something". I have tried the following code:

```
self.url = self.driver.current_url
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.title_contains("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"))
except:
    print "\n IMPERFECT URL \n"
finally:
    self.driver.quit()
```

But this approach uses title search .. I want to check my current url for possible sets of strings. How do I do that? Also I want to check for three sets of strings in the same url. Could somebody help. I am a newbie in Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite getting what exact test you want to perform. At any rate, you can pass a callable and test for anything you want. Here is an example of working code that tests whether `google`, `blah` or `foo` are present in the current URL:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/ldd/src/selenium/chromedriver")

driver.get("http://google.com")

def condition(driver):
    look_for = ("google", "blah", "foo")
    url = driver.current_url
    for s in look_for:
        if url.find(s) != -1:
            return True

    return False

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)

driver.quit()
```

(Obviously, the path to the Chrome driver has to be adapted to your own situation.)

As soon as the return value of `condition` is a true value, the wait ends. Otherwise, a `TimeoutException` will be raised. If you remove `"google"` from `("google", ...)` you'll get a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: I am performing a submit operation in a form. After submit the current page redirects to another page. I want to fetch the url of the redirected page. Did you get it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've imagined some sort of test you could do on ``driver.current_url`` but I'm not sure that's what you had in mind. At any rate, the principle is fully illustrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the `expected_conditions` class not exists a definition for what you want. But you can define your own `expected_conditions` , in this two questions are provided a good explanations about this topic :

- [Selenium Expected Conditions - possible to use 'or'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462177/selenium-expected-conditions-possible-to-use-or)
- [Python Selenium WebDriver. Writing my own expected condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377437/python-selenium-webdriver-writing-my-own-expected-condition?rq=1)

In any case you could use [lambda expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html) to define your function in the `WebDriverWait`.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie and didn't understand the links you referred. And yes there's no EC class for what I want. Do you have any other links?