# Python Selenium: waiting for one element OR another element to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm using this code for waiting for an element to load:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,options=ChromeOpts, desired_capabilities=captain) 
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
openbrowser = browser.get(url) 
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'h1')))
browser.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

However, what I really need is to wait for one element OR another.
So I can, for example, wait for 'h1' OR 'rf-footer'.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the two checks in a single `wait()` operation - by using a python's lambda expression, using the `find_elements_*()` methods glued together with an `or`:

```
element = wait.until(lambda x: x.find_elements_by_id("id1") or x.find_elements_by_css_selector("#id2"))[0]
```

You can use this approach even to get the element that is matched first - the `[0]` at the end.
This solution works, as `find_elements_*()` returns a list of all matched elements, or an empty one if there aren't such (a boolean false). So if the first call doesn't find anything, the second is evaluated; that repeats until either of them finds a match, or the time runs out.

This approach gives the benefit the `wait.until()` will stop immediately after one of the two passes - e.g. speed.

---

Versus a try-catch block - in it, the first condition has to fail (waited for up to X seconds, usually 10), for the second one even to be checked; so if the first is false, while the second true - the runtime/wait is going to be at least X seconds plus whatever time the second check takes.
In the worst case, when both are false, you are in for 2X wait, versus X in combining the two. If you add other conditions, you are only increasing the factor.

Comment: Thanks!! I've tried the first one and got that:
`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'presence_of_element_located'`

Comment: Any ideas for solving it?

Comment: My bad, fat-fingered it on mobile (likewise now, fingers crossed :). The issue was `presence_of_element_located()` is a class in `expected_conditions`, not a method of the webdriver object (which is the `x` in the lambda).

Comment: Now It's occurring another exception. After I execute:
`browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`

**I get:**

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null`

As I'm trying to get the HTML, it seems it's returning null.

Comment: My code:

`browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=ChromeOpts, desired_capabilities=capa) 
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
openbrowser = browser.get(url) #navigate to the page 
a = wait.until(lambda x: EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_max")) or EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "max_id")))
browser.execute_script("window.stop();")
html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")`

BTW, already changed to innerHTML. I see on the console that before the page stops loading, the console's already finalized to run the code.

Comment: I think I got it, I placed a `time.sleep(x)` before running the last script.

Comment: The part with `expected_conditions` is incorrect, because `ec.presence_of_element_located` returns an object and therefore using the `or` operator will always return the part before `or` but the part after `or` will never be executed.

Comment: @JakubBláha you are correct, that won't do the job - but for a different reason. The first `presence_of_element_located()` when the element is not there will not return an object, but will raise an exception - which is caught by the `wait.until()`, and the cycle is repeated. Thus the second `presence_of_element_located()` will actually never be executed - that's the part you're correct about. I'll edit the answer, by keeping only the `find_elements*()` - that will always work as if there are no found, they return empty list (boolean false).

Comment: What exception would it raise though? It doesn't actually do anything until it's called by the `until` method, therefore it cannot raise any exception. The second object was never even instantiated.

Thanks for editing the answe and thanks for providing an actual working solution.

Comment: It raises ElementNotFound, that's handled by the `until()`'s catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `expected_conditions`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

the full solution can be found here: [Selenium Expected Conditions - possible to use 'or'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462177/selenium-expected-conditions-possible-to-use-or)

Comment: Thanks! I got it buy using TRY/EXCEPT.
`openbrowser = browser.get(url) #navigate to the page
    try:
     wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id_stop)))
    except:
     wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'rf-footer')))
    browser.execute_script("window.stop();")`

Answer (score -1):

I got it buy using TRY/EXCEPT.

```
openbrowser = browser.get(url) #navigate to the page 
try: 
   wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, id_stop))) 
except: 
   wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'rf-footer')))
browser.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it will wait for one condition to look for the other.