# Waiting for One of Two Texts

Tags: selenium, webdriver, pytest, wait, selenoid

I'm writing tests in pytest using selenium and selenoid.
I would like to wait and see if one of two texts become visible.

something like this:

```
wait_for_text(text1 OR text2)
```

Is there any way to do this directly without using try and catch?

Answer (score 2):

**Using XPATH logical or**

This will help to limit webdriver requests count to 1 per condition check.

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[(text()='text1') or (text()='text2')]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two checks in a single `wait()` operation - by using a python's lambda expression, using the `find_elements_*()` methods glued together with an `or`:

```py
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='text1']") or x.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='text1']"))
```

For more details see the reference to original solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050601/3485434)

Answer (score 1):

To [wait for either of the texts to be visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70103427/7429447) you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPath* you can pass the expressions through `OR` condition as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='textA' or text()='textB']"))
  ```
- Using *XPath* and [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda) you can pass the expressions through `OR` condition as follows:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[text()='textA']") or driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[text()='textB']"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverWait for multiple conditions (OR logical evaluation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496760/7429447)
- [selenium two xpath tests in one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891188/7429447)
- [Python / Selenium: Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46147830/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that checks for either condition. This one checks for a either class or a text, you can edit it to make it suit your needs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your_website_here")

class ElementPresentOrTextInPage:
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        # Try to find the element
        try:
            element = EC.presence_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
            if element:
                return element
        except:
            pass

        # Check for text in page source
        if self.text in driver.page_source:
            return True

        # Explicitly return False if neither condition is met
        return False

# Usage of custom condition
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element_or_text_present = wait.until(
    ElementPresentOrTextInPage(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, "your-class-name"),
        "text you want to find"
    )
)

# Now 'element_or_text_present' will be the WebElement if found,
# or True if "text found" is in page_source

# Do something based on the result
if element_or_text_present is True or element_or_text_present is not None:
    if isinstance(element_or_text_present, bool):
        # The text "text you want to find" was found
        print("Text found")
    else:
        # The WebElement was found
        print("Element is present")
else:
    print("Neither condition met")
```

Comment: Thanks! Originally, I was hoping for a simple one line solution using selenium but it seems such a solution doesn't exist. This is a completely different approach. I'll have to look at my code and see if your idea would be helpful.