# Is it possible to use an OR statement within WebDriverWait?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Is it possible to use an OR statement with `WebDriverWait`?  Basically I want the code to look for a UPC product code OR a Not Found statement.  Only one or the other will show up on the website, so as soon as it finds either I want to to do something.   If it finds the UPC I want it to click on it.  If it finds the Not Found statement, I want it to append the UPC that wasn't found to a list.  Below is the snippet of code from my larger For Loop.  I'd prefer not to wait for the 10 with an else statement, but sometimes the search function on the website does load slower, so it's nice to have that larger 10 timer.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="'+upc+'"]' OR '/html/body/app-root/div/crf-report-route-entry/crf-report-page/div/div[2]/crf-data-selector-panel/crf-navigation-list/div[2]/p')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [**any_of**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.all_of) [`expected_condition`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#all_of).
As per documentation:

```
An expectation that any of multiple expected conditions is true.
Equivalent to a logical 'OR'.
Returns results of the first matching condition, or False if none do.
```

The example of use of it looks like:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.any_of(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id1")),
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id2"))
    )
)
```

**UPD**
Alternatively you can try using a python's `lambda` expression, using the `find_elements` methods glued together with an **or** operator as following:

```py
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_elements(By.ID, "id1") or x.find_elements(By.ID, "#id2"))
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050601/3485434) for more details

Comment: Thank you.  I'm using Anaconda and Spyder and it looks like they don't have the most current version of Selenium available as I receive this output: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'any_of'

Comment: OK, see the updated answer. Let me know if now it worked for you

Comment: Actually, in the documentation that you linked, I actually just copied the function and added it to my code, and it works great.  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you :)