# Selenium (Java): Do both positive AND negative check whether page is loaded correctly

Tags: java, selenium, assert

In Selenium, there are standard checks whether a page has been loaded technically correct. For example:

```
@FindBy(id = "loginButton")
private WebElement loginButton;

@Override
public void assertLoadedTechnicallyCorrect() {
    WebDriverWait wait = waitWithTimeoutSeconds(10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(loginButton));
}
```

The problem: Often you don't have to wait 10 seconds if the page is loaded or not, as a different page with an error message (let's call it alertMessage) is loaded much faster. In this case, no login button will be on the page.

So expected behavior is:

- Wait until either loginButton or alertMessage is clickable (of course, displayed would be enough for the alertMessage, but it's also clickable).
- If it was loginButton, go on with the test case.
- If it was alertMessage, stop and throw an error message.

A similar question has been posed and answered under [Selenium Expected Conditions - possible to use 'or'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462177/selenium-expected-conditions-possible-to-use-or)

However, the solution suggested there by artfulrobot with defining an "AnyEc" class does not work in the same way, as I need opposite behavior for the different cases - not the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve this.

If that is the case you can use.

```
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.something")),
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.anything"))));
```

and then check separately which element is displayed like

```
if(driver.findelements(By.xpath("loginbutton")).size>0) 
//do loginbutton code part

else if (driver.findelements(By.xpath("error message")).size>0)
 //do error part
```

Comment: There is no defined timeframe. After an arbitrary number of seconds, either the login button or the error message will appear. There is no "before" and "after" - this is the main problem for executing the check.