# How to traverse through inner div tags in Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a html code as below:

```
<div class="abc">
  <div class ="xyz"
   <p> xyz </p>
  </div>

  <div class= "foo">
   <p>foo</p>
   <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="www.google.com" role="button" name="click" id="click">Click me</a>
  <div>
</div>
```

How can I grab the `Click me` button here and do a click using Selenium. I used `driver.find_element_by_id()` but it did not work and gave an error.

I think I might have to traverse through the div tags to reach the button.I tried the below code to grab the div class but not able to proceed.

```
def test(self):
    self.driver.get("sample site address")
    elem = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("abc")
    #need to get to the button and click it?
```

ERROR:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector abc is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_ (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8879)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8910)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8917)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10884)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10889)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpXXYwwK/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831) 

-----
```

Comment: What error did you get when you tried `driver.find_element_by_id()`?

Comment: Given that error, there's two possibilities.  Is the `div` contained in a `frame` or `iframe`?  Is the element slow to load?

Comment: yes , Its a slider , element loads after 4 sec. how can I make my driver to wait for 5 sec?

Comment: (This is just my experience as a beginner with Selenium) I think `find_element_by_class_name` does not find elements that have the "class" attribute set. For that you'd have to do `findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='foo']"))` .... or its equivalent in Python.

Comment: This link has several good approaches you can take for an element that is slow to load: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement

Answer (score 0):

Since, `Click me` is a link, you can find it with link text and then click on it:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Click me")
```