# How Can I wait for an Element will be visible then be clicked in Python Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, odoo

In odoo I have written code to click on the send button that is

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Send']").click()
```

After this send button is clicked , then I have to clicked on "Confirm Sale" button , but at run time it is giving an error like Element is not visible

I have also tried

```
webdriver.wait.until(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Confirm Sale']"))
```

but it arises an error like

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wait'
```

I am sticking 2 images for that
[image: before Send button image - it's a wizard] 
[image: After send button , wizard will be closed & then have to click on confirm sale button]

But here after send button clicked , the workflow state is also changed from "Draft Quotation" to "Quotation Sent" so , how can I wait my webdriver for all these things done & then click on "Confirm Sale" button

I have declared my webdriver like this

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser = self.browser
    browser.get("http://localhost:5555")
```

so please provide me exact code for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium waitForElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement)

Answer (score 7):

You have to import the webdriver wait module. you can do something like the example below. 
Read more abut waits at [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="your/path/to/chromedriver")

# Access website

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
confirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[.='Confirm Sale']")))
confirm.click()
```

Comment: wd is not defined

Comment: wd is the instance of webdriver