# HTML is commented when I use PhantomJS

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to get some data from one web page. The problem is that when I look on the `HTML` code using `Firefox` or any real browser, I can clearly see the "path" to the value I want.

This "path" does not work using `Selenium` - `PhantomJS` `XPath`. The code I'm searching in is commented.

Here you can see `Firefox` code:

[image]

And here - `PhantomJS - driver.page_source`:

[image]

Do you know how to get the `85` in the code?

Comment: I feel like your are retrieving data from DOM while the application is not finished calculation/rendering yet. Have you try webdriver wait yet? See example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement

Comment: Does the element that you want to extract appear when you take a screenshot? Perhaps it appears in another part of the markup.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Probably not since there is no such value in page_source instead of the commented one.