# python selenium how to get link from google

Tags: python, selenium

How do I get a link from Google? I tried the following ways, but none of them worked:

1. `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='r']/@href")`
2. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a").get_attribute("href")`
3. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a").get_attribute(("href")[2])`

I am receiving "none"

I need to get google link, not link to the site (e.g. not www.stackoverflow.com). It's highlighted on this image:

[image]

Comment: Try as `driver.get_element_by_css_selector("h3.r > a").get_attribute("href")` and let me know..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_css_selector' 
i tried "driver.find_element_by_css_selector" but response http://stackoverflow.com  . i have to get other link , as i said

Comment: What do you mean other link??.. and yes it's just typo mistake it should be `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur please look at the picture. i need the right link.
/url?sa=t&rct=j&...

Answer (score 0):

You maye have multiple issues here:
First and third options are a not a valid xpath. Second options may find more than one matches, so it will return the first that fits, which is not necessarily the one you want. So I suggest:

1. Make *find* specific enough to locate a proper element. I'd suggest [find_element_by_link_text](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) if you know the name of the link you are going to choose:

   ```
   link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Stack Overflow')
   ```
2. Given you chose the right link, you should be able to get the attribute:

   ```
   href = link.get_attribute('href')
   ```
3. If the first statement throws an exception (most likely *element not found*), you may need to wait for the element to appear on the page, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement)