# html scraping with python and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I have tried to understand the process to using lxml to pull the text
trying simple python program

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.foo bar')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
name = tree.xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487276887950_2408"]/div[@class="locu-menu-item-name"]/text')
print(name)
```

results in []

values for a nested tag, the xpath is:
//*[@id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487276887950_103789"]/div[1]/div[1]

the value is `<div class="locu-menu-item-name">Italian Lemon Sorbetto</div>`
which is nested like this

```
<div class="menu-item-inner">                      
    <div class="locu-menu-item-name">Italian Lemon Sorbetto</div>
    <div class="locu-menu-item-description">Dairy-free</div>
    <div class="option-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="locu-menu-item-price"></div>
</div>
```

any help would be great.

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to find references and help if you just used css selectors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your xpath. To get the text you should use `/text()` in the end and not `/text`. So your xpath should be like this:

```
name = tree.xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_17_2_1_1487276887950_2408"]/div[@class="locu-menu-item-name"]/text()')
```

When you use `/text`, it means that you are looking for the nested tag text.

```
<div class="locu-menu-item-name"><text>Italian Lemon Sorbetto</text></div>
```

Comment: I understand where the error in my xpath but I changed it from what inspector showed as the xpath when I copy xpath on this element it is: //*[@id="locu-medium-container"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1] , however using either my corrected /text() or the unaltered xpath still results in an empty result. I am really at a loss at where to pull this from.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Could you provide the real url? When I run the xpath 'tree.xpath('//div[@class="locu-menu-item-name"]/text()')' with html that you added I get the text

Comment: @ChuckLaPress so it's a problem with the page load. When you make a call using requests, you don't have your element in the response. Probably after the load of the page JS add the elements. You can use something like 'Selenium' to get this data

Comment: thanks, I understand that however I have very little experience, thank you for clarifying that the problem is the element hasn't loaded when it is trying to pull it.

Comment: One other question I have written some code that is resulting in : <Element div at 0x105bcf208> using selenium could you possible help me get the answer by reviewing what I have written

Comment: @ChuckLaPress I can help you if you have a problem. But you should check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement , to wait for your elements and after use http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html to get your text

Comment: Thank you for the links I am thankful for your help already and the links will get me there. thanks again

Comment: will post code with output still not getting desired string for locu-item-name will be in new topic named python selenium scraping