# Find Element By Text Using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have the following HTML page and I am using Selenium under python to extract some data from the page 
HTML

```
<div class="secondary-content-col col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h2 class="h4"><span>Uthyres av:</span> Test</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the **Test** text from  tag, I have tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'Uthyres')]")
```

but it says element no found!
any idea how can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `xpath`:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Uthyres')]/parent::*/text()
```

instead of `contains(., ...)` use `contains(text(), ...)` and then go to the parent node and extract the text. Note **Test** here is the text node of tag `h2` instead of `span`.

---

Demonstration using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

e = etree.fromstring("""<div class="secondary-content-col col-xs-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h2 class="h4"><span>Uthyres av:</span> Test</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>""")

e.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Uthyres")]/parent::*/text()')
# [' Test']
```

Comment: I tried "driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Uthyres av")]/parent::*/text()')" it didn't work

Comment: It's possible that you are trying to find elements before it loads up. Try adding a wait before find_elements_..., see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement).

Comment: I got this error The result of the xpath expression "//*[contains(text(), "Uthyres av")]/parent::*/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.