# TimeOut Exception handling

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written the code as like below by providing delay (`time.sleep()`), but I wanted modify code by invoking `try` exceptions functionality. So to modify below code.

```
def min_power(self):
        power_min_list = ["Carrier", "@#$%", "-1", "101", "22"]
        time.sleep(6)
        for i in range(len(power_min_list)):
            if i == 0:
                pencil()
            power_min = web.find_element_by_id("powmin")
            power_min.clear()
            power_min.send_keys(power_min_list[i])
            submit()
            time.sleep(3)
            var1 = web.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='grp_powmin']//span[contains(text(),'Number must be between 0 and 100.')]").text
            var2 = "Number must be between 0 and 100."
            if var1 == var2:
                pass
            else:
                print ("Failed - invalid data written successfully")
            if i == 3:
                power_min = web.find_element_by_id("powmin")
                power_min.clear()
                power_min.send_keys(power_min_list[4])
                submit()
        time.sleep(6)
        var = power_min_list[4]
        var3 = web.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='modulation_table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").text
        if var == var3:
            pass
        else:
            print ("Failed - Power Min wrong Data is written successfully")
```

Comment: ...and the question is...?

Comment: here the question is how to modify this code by invoking try exception block ? and that will be generic for entire definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait for element instead time.sleep()

[Selenium waitForElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement)

You cannot remove sleep in second line in method min_power?