# How to click button using selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="btnPermission">GO</button>
```

The above codes are from a website, however I am unable to click this button despite trying multiple attempts. What should I do?

```
 IWebElement reklamgec3 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#btnPermission"));
 ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", reklamgec3);



IWebElement reklamgec3 = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-outline-primary"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", reklamgec3)


IWebElement reklamgec3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnPermission"]"));
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", reklamgec3)


 IWebElement reklamgec3 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnPermission"));
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", reklamgec3)

      IWebElement reklamgec3 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#btnPermission"));
        reklamgec3.Click();
```

How to click button using c# selenium. The above does not work for me.

Comment: Can't you call [`Click()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Click.htm) directly on `reklamgec3`?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you want to [edit] the question and list all options you tried. Otherwise you'll get a lot of suggestions that are not useful.

Comment: I added those that don't work for me

Comment: I think @ThomasWeller is saying `reklamgec3.Click()` since the Click() method is a method on the IWebElement interface.  Have you put a breakpoint on to see if `reklamgec3` actually has a value?

Comment: No. I didn't put it because i don't know how.

Comment: "It does not work" is a vague description. Does it throw an exception? If so, what exception?

Comment: I'm getting a no such element unable to locate element error.

Comment: I agree to @squillman: you certainly should know how to put a breakpoint. Maybe watch this: https://youtu.be/KZ7J4VryLE8?t=98

Comment: If there is no such element, but you see it when you have a look at the website manually, chances are that the element is not available at page load but is added later by JavaScript. You then need something like [Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251939/wait-until-button-is-clicked-in-selenium-webdriver-to-click-on-next-button) or [Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992993/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-wait-until-element-is-present)

Comment: What should I do in this situation? @ThomasWeller

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/):

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("btnPermission")).Click());
```

Waiting for the existence of a element is frequently not enough. You need to wait for it to be clickable. Many times that just means attempting to find then click the element until the click event succeeds.

Comment: Hi @Greg. Can you plz check this one too..Thank u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044226/selenium-webdriver-not-working-correctly-on-button-click-events-what-is-the-iss