# selenium can't locate the element

Tags: python, css, selenium

selenium can't locate the element.
The error info:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"loadAllUpcomingPast"}
```

my code is:

```
url_base = 'http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=&pg=all'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url_base)

time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.frame("signupFrame")

driver.find_element_by_id("close_signup").click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("loadAllUpcomingPast").click()
```

the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I cannot browse http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=&pg=all

Comment: the whole url is http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=lama&pg=all

Comment: Still cannot that

Comment: The correct url should be [this](http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=&pg=all)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement

Comment: http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=lama&pg=all

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the `loadAllUpcomingPast` gets loaded later on. You could try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


url_base = 'http://www.christies.com/lotfinder/searchresults.aspx?&searchtype=p&action=paging&searchFrom=header&lid=1&entry=lama&pg=all'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url_base)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

try:
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'loadAllUpcomingPast')))
    print(f'Element found: {element}')
except TimeoutException:
    print('could not find loadAllUpcomingPast')
```

In my console I see:

```
Element found: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c9f1b83164f34001aa0a98581618d45b", element="0.6182317130585246-1")>
```

This will tell Selenium to wait until that element is clickable. You can adjust the wait time if needed within the `WebDriverWait` 2nd argument.

Comment: it seems something wrong, element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, 'loadAllUpcomingPast'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I adjust time to 30, still can't locate the element.thx buddy! appreciate for your help!

Comment: @Goodmanyeahhh it works for me. I edited the post with a print statement and it shows me the element. Unsure as to why it does not work for you.

Comment: when open the page, a registration window appeared.so I used the code:"driver.switch_to.frame("signupFrame")
driver.find_element_by_id("close_signup").click()" to close the window,and then click the load all button.Could the problem be here?

Comment: the code is work, I change new network, it works! thanks!