# Selenium not identifying any element in particular HTML, why?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of URLs that I need to iterate over. The process I am working on is that selenium opens each of the URLs in the list, clicks a button to open the form, and pass some strings into the form.

I have gotten to the point of clicking the button to open the form. I can not pass in any strings into the form however using any of the elements. I get error 'Unable to locate element'

This is my code so far, `easily_apply` is list of the URLs:

```
for i in easily_apply:
    driver.get(i)
    test = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
    test.click()
    test.find_element_by_name("applicant.name")
    test.send_keys("John Smith")
```

This is the HTML in question:

```
<input type="text" aria-describedby="label-input-applicant.name-error" aria-labelledby="label-input-applicant.name" id="input-applicant.name" name="applicant.name" class="icl-TextInput-control icl-TextInput-control--sm">
```

Thank you in advance.

edit:

Code with xpath, not working, getting error 'Unable to locate elements':

```
for i in easily_apply:
    driver.get(i)
    test = driver.find_element_by_class_name('indeed-apply-button')
    test.click()
    test.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]')
    test.send_keys("John Smith")
```

edit2:

code with wait in it, still getting same error 'Unable to locate elements':

```
for i in easily_apply:
    driver.get(i)
    test = driver.find_element_by_class_name('indeed-apply-button')
    test.click()
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,60)
    test.find_element_by_name('applicant.name')
    test.send_keys("John Smith")
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781792/selenium-waitforelement

Comment: Hi, I was just looking at that, I made a edit with my new code with the wait code appended into it. Still getting the same error.

Comment: The best solution is to use wait after switching to the frame as Satish suggests. Also, you probably have to wait for the iframe too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the html, assuming you are using the code from your previous post, obtaining all the easily apply list.

The element you are looking for is inside nested iframe. you need to switch to that iframe and then look for the element

Replace the time.sleep with Webdriverwait

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="indeed-apply-button"]').click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[name*=indeed-ia]'))

import time
time.sleep(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
driver.find_element_by_id('input-applicant.name').send_keys('Applicant Name')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much Satish!

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath.

> In Selenium automation, if the elements are not found by the general locators like id, class, name, etc. then XPath is used to find an element on the web page .

Syntax is:
**Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made a edit, where I tried using xpath but I am still getting the same error I mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe you need WebDriverWait to wait until element is visible. Implicit or Explicit wait can be used . Or you can use Thread. sleep(milliseconds)

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); will wait for 1 minute

Comment: Made edit with webdriverwait code still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

```html
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#jl_1c27f21fec51d296 > a").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="indeed-apply-button"]').click()
```